# Retrieving status from Asterisk using PHP

Tags: php, command-line-interface, asterisk, agi

today I am again in need of assistance regarding my problem. I have this code which sends sms through asterisk using the CLI command. Forgive me if you were to find some error in my code. I just started learning php 2 days ago. I need help as to how can I get the status of the SMS that I sent to a receiver. I'm actually using the **phpagi** library that I found in sourceforge website.

The Code:

```
        $num = $_POST['phonenumber'];
        $num2 = $_POST['phonenumber2'];
        $num3 = explode(',', $num);
        $msg =  'This is a system generated message: '.$_POST['message'].' || For additional information kindly reply here: '.$num2;
        $type='gsm';
        $method='send';
        $sync='sync sms';
        $span='4';
        $message=$msg;
        $timeout='20';
        //$id='1234';
        for($var = 0; $var < count($num3); $var++)
        {
            $destination=$num3[$var];
            $chunks=wordwrap($message, 155,'\\');
            $final=explode('\\', $chunks);

            foreach ($final as $key => $total) {
                //echo "Key: $key; Value: \"$total\"";
                $total= '"'.$total.'"';
                 $agi->Command("$type $method $sync $span $destination $total $timeout");                   
            }
        }
```

[image]

Accessing asterisk using SSH **putty**:

How can I get this status "Successfully" using PHP and display it on the PHP page. Thanks in advance

Comment: Why the down vote without explanation? :o

Comment: How is that output generated? Or rather, why doesn't the API provide this information?

Comment: That output is generated using the keyword "sync" as you can see in the printscreen above. Without that keyword, that status won't display as told from the pdf file that I downloaded from the manufacturer website. But it doesn't say how to retrieve that status using other commands.

Comment: Doesn't `$agi->Command()` not give you that output? Also, it would help to mention which API you're developing against.

Comment: No it doesn't give me that output. But if it does I don't really now to retrieve it and put that in a variable then display in the page. This the php class that I'm working with http://sourceforge.net/projects/phpagi/files/
This is the sample demo of the Manufacturer site http://demo.openvox.cn:65321/cgi-bin/php/sms-outbox.php

Comment: Have you try to catch response and echo as- `$response = $agi->Command("your command"); echo $response;`

Comment: I tried your suggestion @jagad89 It did display now. This is the response message "Privilege: Command SPAN:4 SEND SMS TO PHONE:09123456789 SUCCESSFULLY Follows"

Comment: So `$agi->Command()` *does* give you that output. Then, just either use `strpos()` or `preg_match()` to determine whether it was successful.

Comment: @Jack  Yes, You have to parse output to get your desire output.

Comment: Ok thanks for your help guys. I'm gonna read some information regarding those functions now @Ja͢ck :D Thanks again guys!

Answer (score 0):

I see you are gooing ask every odd step you do on this site, right?

For sms send you will not get any response.

You can patch asterisk to fire event on that or create custom script which will parse log.

Relative simple option is create call to Local channel and use dialplan command sendSMS, after that analyze variables it set (check in asterisk "core show application like SMS")

Comment: Hello there sir, I have tried putting the agi command in a variable and echo that variable as suggested by jagad89 above in the comment section.
$response = $agi->Command("your command"); echo $response;
fortunately it did fire a response and I was able to display it in the page. Thanks again for the suggestion. One more question sir, does the dialplan command contains something which would receive sms messages?

Comment: your sms stack is not standart. check in asterisk console using "core show application like SMS"

Comment: Hello again sir. It outputs "Your application(s) is (are) not registered Command 'core show application like SMS' failed". What does it mean?

Comment: debugging is not topic at stackoverflow. try command applicable for your asterisk version.

Comment: ohh .. says here I'm running asterisk 1.8.20.0 built by root @ freeom.centos on a i686 running Linux

Comment: remove "core" at start

Comment: I tried removing the "core" but it outputs 'no such command'. BTW sorry for the very late reply.

Comment: This site is not source of your debug. Seams like you dooing no effort. Please go to asterisk.org forums